# get statusCode inside jQuery load event handler

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-codes

I'm using jQuery ajax event 'load':

## markup code:

```
<iframe id="my_iframe" src="http://somewhere"></iframe>
```

## jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#my_frame').load(function(statusCode) {
        // The content loaded here maybe 404/500 or other.
        if(statusCode == 400) {
            // do something.
        } else {
            // do something else.
        }
    });
});
```

## Question

I want to get the status code in my load event callback. Maybe get the `jqXHR` object to achieve?

Is this possible?

---

More, I may manually change the src attribute of the iframe, which will also trigger the `load` event, it seems this is not an ajax call.

Comment: You only have a callback and no loading-url, what are you loading?, also you can use the XHR-object if defined in the callback paramaters.

Comment: @AdrianForsius could you please point me a more specifically way about how to put the XHR-object into callback as parameter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I load an url in iframe with Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177080/how-do-i-load-an-url-in-iframe-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, it is generally not best practice to use *iframes*. You should be able to accomplish all of your requirements simply using a `<div>` element.

**Html:**

```
<div id="dynamicPage">
    Loading...
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#dynamicPage").load(
"http://somewhere",
function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "success") {
        // SUCCESSFUL request //

    } else if (status == "error" || status == "timeout") {
        // ERROR and TIMEOUT request //

        var msg = "Sorry! An error has occurred. Please try again later";
        $("#dynamicPage").html(msg);

    } else if (status == "notmodified") {
        // NOT MODIFIED request (likely cached) //

    } else if (status == "abort") {
        // ABORTED request //

    }
});
```

Tread carefully with some of the other suggested on this question. Another post did not even use `jQuery.load()` and mispelled "`success:`" as "`sucess.`"

*As a bonus treat (if you are possibly intrigued), you may easily adapt the code above to utilize a loading animation.*

***Reference:*** [Basic jQuery animation: Elipsis (three sequential dots)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26673789/2456401)

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are looking for something like this:

```
$.get({
    'url': 'your-url',
    sucess: function(response, status, xhr) {
        //do something

        //Change the iframe content by src while having xhr availible
        $('#my_frame').attr('src', 'new-url');
        //Change the iframe content by appending your own HTML while having xhr availible
        $('#my_frame').contents().append('<div>New HTML</div>');

    },
    error: function (response, status, xhr) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, if I wrote this way on an `div`, it works, but I'm now working on an iframe, that seemed not loading content correctly. Is there any way works if I load the content by changing `src` of that iframe?

Comment: What you probably then want to do is what is discussed in this question, probably you don't want to use load but change the src-attribute on the iframe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177080/how-do-i-load-an-url-in-iframe-with-jquery

Comment: Well, I know how to change the src attribute, then make the iframe load the page, but if I load the iframe in this way, I can't get the xhr object and status as that in your answer.